# Toolbar se me oculta una vez para todas las vistas

Tags: android, kotlin

Veréis, tengo un problema: tengo una toolbar que se muestra en mi Activity para que esté visible en los fragments que maneja dicho activity. En algunos quiero que se muestre pero en otros no, entonces para hacer que no se muestre he utilizado:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Y efectivamente, hace lo que tiene que hacer. El problema viene que cuando cambio del fragment donde se ve la toolbar, a un fragment donde está oculto, si después vuelvo al fragment donde debería aparecer dicha barra, esta ha desaparecido también ahí, la pregunta es: ¿como hago para que solo desaparezca donde quiero?

Este es el fragment donde lo estoy ocultando:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import com.isaac.lookatme.R

class ContactFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): ContactFragment = ContactFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false)

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.hide()

    }


}
```

Este es el activity que se encarga de manejar los diferentes fragment, y creo que donde radica el problema, ya que me he fijado que cuando estoy en un fragment, y voy pasando entre ellos, si después en los botones de navegación del movil le doy hacía atrás, pasa por todos los que he abierto, por lo que supongo que esos fragment quedan en memoria, pero no se como hacer en Kotlin para manejar que no queden así, asi que si podéis ayudarme en eso, os lo agradezco:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.isaac.lookatme.R
import com.isaac.lookatme.fragments.ContactFragment
import com.isaac.lookatme.fragments.EducationFragment
import com.isaac.lookatme.fragments.ExperienceFragment
import com.isaac.lookatme.fragments.HomeFragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, HomeFragment.newInstance()).commit()

        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.isaac -> {
                    val fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
                    openFragment(fragment)
                    true
                }
                R.id.contact -> {
                    val fragment = ContactFragment.newInstance()
                    openFragment(fragment)
                    true
                }
                R.id.education -> {
                    val fragment = EducationFragment.newInstance()
                    openFragment(fragment)
                    true
                }
                R.id.work -> {
                    val fragment = ExperienceFragment.newInstance()
                    openFragment(fragment)
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))

    }

    private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }

}
```

Una posible solución que le he encontrado ha sido en el fragment donde quiero que se muestre, en el metodo onResume(), poner:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.show()
```

De esta forma me la muestra, pero de todas formas me sigue teniendo mosca el problema de que los fragment se queden almacenados en memoria.

Comment: Y si haces el cambio en el `bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListene{}` ? has probado con esa opción ?

Comment: Pues si, es otra opción bastante más sencilla que no se me había ocurrido :) Muchas gracias!